# Excel.Style: Add method of Styles class failed

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

This was working fine until I added it in a loop. I think it happens because I am adding the style twice.

I am trying to add a style to the first row of the sheet.

```
if (LastRowInsertionIndex==1)
{
    xlWorkSheet.Activate();
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "CaseNumber";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Names";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Bar Number";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Email";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Title";

    Excel.Style style = WorkBook.Styles.Add("NewStyle");

    //style.Font.Name = "Verdana";
    style.Font.Size = 14;
    style.Font.Bold = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Style = style;
}
```

`Excel.Style style = WorkBook.Styles.Add("NewStyle");` causes the error;

```
Add method of Styles class failed
```

And I am having to select each cell in the first column 1 by one. Is there a way to select all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Workbook.Styles` does not appear to have an indexer, you could implement a lazy-load method like this:

```
private Dictionary<Excel.Workbook, Excel.Style> _MyStyle =
    new Dictionary<Excel.Workbook, Excel.Style>();
private Excel.Style MyStyle(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
    Excel.Style myStyle;
    if (!_MyStyle.TryGetValue(Wb, out myStyle))
    {
        myStyle = Wb.Styles.Add("NewStyle");

        myStyle.Font.Name = "Verdana";
        myStyle.Font.Size = 14;
        myStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        _MyStyle.Add(Wb, myStyle);
    }

    return myStyle;
}
```

And then implement it like this:

```
if (LastRowInsertionIndex == 1)
{
    xlWorkSheet.Activate();
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "CaseNumber";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Names";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Bar Number";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Email";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Title";

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Style = MyStyle(Workbook);
}
```

Alternatively, you could loop through each Style in the workbook, but the more times you call it and the more styles you have the more inefficient it will be.

Another advantage of the lazy load approach is if you implement multiple styles, you can pass that as an additional parameter.